# How can I generate HTML documents for all packages inside a folder using godoc

Tags: go, godoc

`godoc -html` generates documents for only one package.  However, I want to ship the project with all documents for all packages, just like when I run `godoc -http`.  With that, I could find all packages and navigate through them from the browser.

Is it possible to generate HTML pages for all packages **linked together** through `godoc -html`?

Comment: hmm, are you hosting the docs yourself? or do you expect this to stay in go doc reference?

Comment: I think it will be a separate repository holding the documents (HTML Files) for this project, so any one of the team could easily read it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38338422/1267177 might help, maybe have a look, or I'd do some bash scripting and generate in CI server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two questions here:

> Is it possible to generate HTML pages for all packages linked together through godoc -html?

No. Because it is not implemented into godoc (https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc).

The other question:

> How can I generate HTML documents for all packages inside a folder
>   using godoc

I think the simplest way is to start godoc with the http flag: `godoc -http=:6060`

Then you navigate to the folder you want to get the docs. For that url you can use a webcrawler for getting the html documentation. There are already some crawler in Go (https://godoc.org/?q=crawler), if you don't want to write a crawler by your own.

Answer (score 1):

I developed [Golds](https://github.com/go101/golds), which is an alternate Go docs generation tool (and a local docs server / code reader). Hope you this tool would satisfy your need.

Under your project directory, you can run any of the following commands to generate HTML docs for your Go project:

- golds -gen -nouses -plainsrc -wdpkgs-listing=promoted ./...
- golds -gen -nouses -wdpkgs-listing=promoted ./...
- golds -gen -wdpkgs-listing=promoted ./...

The first command generates the most compact docs and the last one generates the full docs, which size is 6 times of the compact docs.